# Objective-C Delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c

delegate:self means it's the same file
How do you define another class/file to respond to delegate events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` means the same object — not file. if you want to set a delegate to another object, just set it:

```
object.delegate = anotherObject;
```

Comment: @Jenny, most often you can see a class as a blue-print for objects.

Comment: A useful recource for learning object-orientated programming in conjunction with Objective-C: [Object-Oriented Programming with Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005149)